# Slackbots node.js get usernames

Tags: node.js, slack-api, slack

Using Slackbots(https://www.npmjs.com/package/slackbots) I was hoping to build a simple message forwarding bot (i.e. when the bot receives a direct message, it shoots it into a chat room and says who it is from) but I can't seem to get it to push out user names, only user ID's. Any idea here?

```html
var SlackBot = require('slackbots');
var bot = new SlackBot({
    token: 'xoxb-',
    name: 'helper'
});

bot.on('start', function() {
    var params = {
        icon_emoji: ':cat:'
    };
    bot.postMessageToChannel('helpertest', 'meow!', params);
});

bot.on('message', function(data) {
    bot.postMessageToChannel('helpertest', data.text + data.user.name);

})
```